# scipt for git auto-commit: strange path warning

Tags: git, bash

I want to have certain files / directories monitored and any changes committed to a git repo in order to have a backup history.

The components are:

- A git repository, configured with the variable "worktree" pointing to my home dir
- a text file with a list of all files / dirs to be monitored
- a bash script with the git commands to add and commit changes
- a cronjob running the script

autocommit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit

for path in `cat list.txt`; do
    git add "$path"
    git commit -am "autocommit"
done
```

list.txt:

```
.
~/bcg/credentials.txt
```

If I run ./autocommit.sh with credentials.txt modified, I get the following output

```
~/bcg/credentials.txt
fatal: pathspec 'bcg/versioned/~/bcg/credentials.txt' did not match any files
```

However, the changes are committed.
What does this "fatal" warning mean?

Comment: I would not use '~' in a crontab because it's a bash-ism and might not be supported by more sh-like shells.

Comment: Is this relevant on a modern Ubuntu installation with default cron config? If not, I don't care. I don't need portability, this just needs to work on my personal PC.

Comment: A lot of people got burned when RHES changed /bin/sh from bash to dash.

Comment: Home directory `~` expansion was introduced in **csh**, many years before bash existed. It's POSIX. The only shells that don't support it now are proprietary unix shells still based on Bourne.

Comment: Yes, and many versions of cron use Bourne-like shells, not bash.  Is it really so hard to change '~' to $HOME?

Comment: didn't know that this is such an issue. Thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the cronjob to:

```
22 *  * * *     cd ~/bcg && versioned/autocommit.sh 2>> err.log
```

And remove ~/bcg from list.txt

Comment: that's a problem bcs some of the files to be monitored are not in bcg dir

Comment: I found out the issue is not cronjob specific, thus I edited my question for simplification.